# Given a vector of structs, how can I get an iterator for a specific member of each struct?

Tags: c++, iterator

Let's say I have this struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
  int my_member;
};
```

and this `vector`:

```
vector<MyStruct> my_vec = ...;
```

Let's say I want to pass all these `my_member` values to a function that expects an iterator of numbers:

```
template<class iterator_type>
double process_some_numbers(iterator_type begin, iterator_type end) {
    ...
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this (without defining my own custom iterator from scratch)?

Comment: Can you change your struct (say, `operator int`)?

Comment: If you have boost, you can use the `transform_iterator`. If not, you will probably need to write your own.

Comment: Are you solely against *making* the iterator? What about using a library?

Comment: @JonathanPotter That was about converting vectors, this is about converting iterators. Near match, but for this `*` `++` `--` need to be overloaded, not `[]`.

Comment: I second the comment about [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) I have used it in the past exactly for this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you think copying will be more expensive than changing the iterator for this particular example (in terms of CPU rather than RAM)?

Comment: what's wrong with defining your own custom iterator? it literally takes 4 lines of code - https://ideone.com/9deAbt

Comment: `process_some_numbers` should be defined to accept a functor

Comment: @Ap31 While this minimal example might work in most cases, you still need to provide the correct typedef's (for example such that `std::iterator_traits<I>::reference` to be the correct type, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator)

Comment: Why not use std::for_each or other similar method? You only need define your customize function that how your  MyStruct processed